# Which goal should be chosen for ARCoachingOverlayView when detecting faces or images?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

`ARCoachingOverlayVew` has 4 goal types: `horizontalPlane`, `verticalPlane`, `anyPlane` and `tracking`.

But the Reality Composer has 5 types of anchor:

[image]

Apparently, the first two are for when the  horizontal

What mode should I adjust the `ARCoachingOverlayVew` when I am tracking `Image` or `Face`?  `horizontalPlane`, `verticalPlane`, `anyPlane` or `tracking`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `ARCoachingOverlayView` with `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration`  you should choose `tracking` case:

```
ARCoachingOverlayView.Goal.tracking
```

And when using `ARCoachingOverlayView` with `ARImageTrackingConfiguration`  you should choose `anyPlane` case:

```
ARCoachingOverlayView.Goal.anyPlane
```

Comment: fantastic, thanks. How do you know this stuff? Magic? :)

Comment: [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62576615/unable-to-detect-images-with-reality-kit-when-using-external-images) if you want to grab some points... 

Comment: Hi @Duck, I'll answer it tomorrow)

Comment: No problem, take your time.