# Is there a way to programmatically change the material of an Entity that was created in Reality Composer?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I want to change the color of an entity programmatically after it was created in Reality Composer.

As Reality Composer does not create a ModelEntity (it creates a generic Entity), it does not appear that I have access to change its color.  When I typecast to a ModelEntity, I now have access to the ModelComponent materials.  However, when I try to add that to the scene I get a Thread 1: signal SIGABART error.  Could not cast value of type 'RealityKit.Entity' (0x1fcebe6e8) to 'RealityKit.ModelEntity' (0x1fceba970).  Sample code below.

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        // Load the "Box" scene from the "Experience" Reality File
        let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
    
        // Typecast Steelbox as ModelEntity to change its color
        let boxModelEntity = boxAnchor.steelBox as! ModelEntity
    
        // Remove materials and create new material
        boxModelEntity.model?.materials.removeAll()
    
        let blueMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: .blue, isMetallic: false)
        boxModelEntity.model?.materials.append(blueMaterial)
    
        // Add the box anchor to the scene
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Model entity is stored deeper in RealityKit's hierarchy, and as you said, it's `Entity`, not `ModelEntity`. So use downcasting to access `mesh` and `materials`:

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let boxScene = try! Experience.loadBox()
        print(boxScene)
        
        let modelEntity = boxScene.steelBox?.children[0] as! ModelEntity
        let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .green, isMetallic: false)
        modelEntity.model?.materials = [material]
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        anchor.scale = [5,5,5]
        modelEntity.setParent(anchor)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
}
```

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76150091/alternative-for-findentitynamed-method-to-find-a-specific-model-in-realitykit/76152401#76152401) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532680/realitykit-what-is-steelbox-instance-loading) can be helpful.

Comment: I added the children subscript to the code I posted above and it worked using the existing Reality Composer anchor.  I struggled with this for hours, thank you!  I need to read more about children.  The print command on the scene is also a great tip.

Comment: Glad about that)) For box scene you can also use subscript `boxScene.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0]` instead of `boxScene.steelBox?.children[0]`.

Comment: @AndyJazz is there any way to get a ModelEntity instead of an Entity directly from the Reality Composer? Or the only way is to recursively traverse all its children?

Comment: @TheoK, of course there is. Please publish your question and code.

Comment: @TheoKallioras, Did you ever do what Andy Jazz asked you to do?  Where should I look to get the answer to your question?

Comment: I have updated my answer (added two links).