# ARKit and Reality Composer scaling nodes

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I'm trying to create a node in xcode that will combine 2 of my models that I'm fetching from RC Scene.

```
myTrack
myCar
```

they both been aligned individually but they are a bit too big.
Car is using a loop that is controlling it movement around the track using JSON.

I want to add them to one root node and mange scale from there using

```
let mainAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0, 0, 0])
    
self.arView.scene.addAnchor(mainAnchor)
myTrackTransformed.addChild(mainAnchor)
myCar.addChild(mainAnchor)
    
mainAnchor.scale = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
```

but whatever I put in scale values they do nothing. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

The anchor must be a parent node, not vice versa:

```
let mainAnchor = AnchorEntity()
    
mainAnchor.addChild(myTrack)
mainAnchor.addChild(myCar)
self.arView.scene.addAnchor(mainAnchor)
    
mainAnchor.scale /= 10
```

But remember that you need to extract the [model entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66508129/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-change-the-material-of-an-entity-that-was-cre/66509678#66509678) (`myTrack` and `myCar`) from the Reality Composer scene (`RCScene.rcproject`).