# How can I load a scene from RC as a ModelEntity instead of a plain Entity?

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I am trying to load an `Entity` into my code from a scene in a Reality Composer project.

I am reaching out directly to the autogenerated `.reality` file because I do not want it placed automatically on the first plane it detects. I followed the documentation found in the article [Taking Control of Scene Anchoring](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/taking-control-of-scene-anchoring).

The sample project name is `Experience` and in there I have 2 scenes.

1. The autogenerated Box that comes automatically with a newly created project.
2. A Hexagon shaped imported USDZ file.

The code I use to load both as a `ModelEntity` is the following:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Experience", 
                        withExtension: "reality")!
            .appending(path: "SceneName", directoryHint: .notDirectory)
        
let modelEntity = try! Entity.loadModel(contentsOf: url)
```

where `SceneName` is either the `Box` or the `Hexagon`.

Both fail to load.

If I instead use the following code they succeed, but they are loaded as an `Entity` not as a `ModelEntity`:

```
let modelEntity = try! Entity.load(contentsOf: url)
```

Is it possible to have objects loaded as a `ModelEntity` instead of an `Entity`? The method I am using so far, which I found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66509678), is to traverse the children hierarchy, find the first `ModelEntity`, and copy its model and physics onto its parent, (which in my case works since I only have one object in the scene).

---

**Edit**: Even if I name the objects within the Scene and then try to get them with the `findEntity(named:)` method on the "root" `Entity` object found in the Scene, I again get an `Entity` and not a `ModelEntity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Reality Composer's `.rcproject`

In case you're using Reality Composer's `Experience.rcproject` file, try the following technique. Implement `findEntity(named:)` method and then use typecast `as!` operator to grab the desired model entity from RC scene.

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    typealias ModelPack = ModelEntity & HasPhysicsBody
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene1 = try! Experience.loadBox()
        let scene2 = try! Experience.loadHexagon()
        
        print(scene1); print(scene2)
        
        let boxModel = scene1.findEntity(named: "simpBld_root") as! ModelPack
        let hexModel = scene2.findEntity(named: "simpBld_root") as! ModelPack
        boxModel.position.x = -0.075
        hexModel.position.x = 0.075
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity()     // any RealityKit or ARKit anchor
        anchor.scale *= 3
        anchor.addChild(boxModel)
        anchor.addChild(hexModel)
        
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
}
```

#### `.reality` file

Apple proprietary `.reality` format serves for a faster uploading time. Use the following approach to load `.reality` file into your 3D scene. Remember every RealityKit's scene is entities' hierarchy.

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    typealias ModelPack = ModelEntity & HasPhysicsBody
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let entity = try! Entity.load(named: "SomeScene.reality")
        print(entity)
        
        let boxModel = entity.findEntity(named: "simpBld_root") as! ModelPack
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(.face)
        anchor.addChild(boxModel)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer.

When I inspect the children hierarchy I find that sometimes the models are many levels deep. For example, in the simple USD file I imported, which just shows a simple hexagon shape, I see that the `ModelEntity` is "burried" 5 levels deep. What's the purpose of its ancestors? If I disregard them, will that have any kind of negative impact?

Comment: Any Entity acts as a container with transform parameters and as a group (node) for other entities (such as models, anchors, cameras, etc). In a 3D scene, Entities' hierarchies cannot be ignored.

Comment: And another question. With the proposed solution, I need to know in advance the existing children hierarchy, otherwise I won't be able to know the specific name of the child that is a `ModelEntity`. This means that I need to inspect the hierarchy in advance, and then hardcode the name of the child; or to do a recursive search each time. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: Any file (be it `.usdz`, `.reality` or `.rcproject`) already has a generated final scene, which means you can easily find out the hierarchical relationships of objects using the `print` command  for decomposition (parsing) of this scene.