# How to make grouped objects in one Reality Composer scene draggable?

Tags: swift, collision-detection, uitapgesturerecognizer, realitykit, reality-composer

So I have a Reality Composer file "Experience" loaded onto an XCode project with three scenes.

I have added behaviors and actions that work in XCode. The actions work perfectly, hiding and showing the 2 other scenes when I click on the different objects.

But on one scene, named "cubes", I added two cubes. I grouped these two cubes as "twoCubes" whereby, according to Apple's documentation, they will now behave as a single object:

> You can combine multiple assets in a scene into a group. Grouped
> objects behave as a single combined object in Reality Composer’s scene
> view.

There are no associated actions on this scene, **I only wanted to make the two cubes draggable and scalable when I pinch.** I haven't been able to make that happen. Even when I name each one of the cubes differently, nothing happens.

I suspect it has something to do with what happens when objects are grouped [reference from Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/arranging-elements-in-a-scene#Collect-Assets-into-Groups)  ] but I haven't been able to figure out a solution. I've looked at a lot of answers from resident genius [Andy Jazz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6599590/andy-jazz) who is the expert on this subject, but nothing... I am doing this because I have a much larger model I am working on my own application, that has about 20 children per scene... so I am hoping I can figure out a solution here that I can use for something much larger, later...

[image: see the two cubes to the right]

[image: screenshot of the Reality Composer scenes]

I have tried multiple Reality Composer models where I was able to drag when viewing the reality file on my phone, but that capability was removed once I imported the scenes into an Xcode model.

I have tried everything, including a single cube... and dragging doesn't work either.

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
        
        let cubesAnchor = try! Experience.loadCubes()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(cubesAnchor)
                   
        guard let addingGestures = cubesAnchor.twoCubes as? ModelEntity else { return }
        addingGestures.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
        arView.installGestures([.all], for: addingGestures as (Entity & HasCollision))            
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0){
            self.arView.scene.anchors.removeAll()
            let coneAnchor = try! Experience.loadCone()
            self.arView.scene.anchors.append(coneAnchor)                
            print(coneAnchor)                
        }
        
        func handleTapOnEntity(_ entity: Entity?) {
            guard let entity = entity else { return }  
        }
    }
}
```

See related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76139028/adding-gestures-to-all-model-entities-in-one-reality-composer-scene-not-just-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What `Models Grouping` actually means

In Reality Composer and RealityKit, grouping several objects together means combining several children under single parent (i.e. `parenting` op). Grouped objects can be simultaneously moved, rotated and scaled using their Parent Entity. However, this cannot be applied to the physics – or in other words, collisions, various dynamics forces, raycasting and three types of RealityKit gestures (EntityGestureRecognizer).

As you wrote, this is unambiguously stated in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/arranging-elements-in-a-scene#Collect-Assets-into-Groups).

> If you’ve enabled physics in your scene, grouped objects still behave as separate, individual objects.

Thus, if you grouped models in Reality Composer, you can't make the two cubes `draggable` / `scalable` when you apply corresponding `pan` or `pinch` gestures to a group. Nevertheless, there is one workaround.

#### Workaround

In RealityKit, create an empty group as a ModelEntity. Make its CollisionShape larger than both models. In this case, you can use `pan`, `rotate` and `pinch` gestures to control several objects at once. You can generate [collision shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76139478/custom-collision-shape-appears-in-wrong-position/76139693#76139693) as `box`, `sphere`, `capsule`, and `convex`. You can also create your collision shape from [separate parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73287427/applying-downward-force-to-an-object-using-realitykit/73648884#73648884).

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.arView.debugOptions = .showPhysics
        
        let sph01 = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.05))
        sph01.position.x = -0.1
        let sph02 = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.05))
        sph02.position.x = 0.1
    
        let group = ModelEntity() as ModelEntity & HasCollision
        group.addChild(sph01)
        group.addChild(sph02)
        
        group.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
        self.arView.installGestures(.all, for: group)
        
        let shape = ShapeResource.generateSphere(radius: 0.16)
        let collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [shape],
                                             mode: .trigger,
                                           filter: .sensor)    
        group.components.set(collision)
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        anchor.addChild(group)
        anchor.scale = [5,5,5]
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)    
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Andy Jazz, THE LEGEND, for answering my question. I tested it and it works perfectly! However, I still have one remaining issue which was addressed in a question you answered yesterday ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76136568/how-can-i-load-a-scene-from-rc-as-a-modelentity-instead-of-a-plain-entity/76136791#76136791 ). Like the person who asked the question, I struggle with the findEntity(named: ) method for Reality Composer because all objects within the scene have the same name "simpBld_root" even when I name them on RC. findEntity(named: ) didn't work.

Comment: I need to go back to the documentation and study parenting better as you mentioned. Is there an alternative for the findEntity(named: ) method on RC? I tried calling the objects by name but it didn't work. Only when I used sceneName.objectName and the Entity & hasCollision ...for example let greenCubesGest = cubesAnchor.greenCube as? Entity & HasCollision
        arView.installGestures(for: greenCubesGest!) but this won't work here as the goal is to call each object as a ModelEntity

Comment: Hi @Manuela, Create a new question – include the model and your code, please. Tomorrow I'll answer it.

Comment: Thank you so much, Andy, I added a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76150091/is-there-an-alternative-for-the-findentitynamed-method-to-find-a-specific-mo