# How to add gestures to two model entities in two different scenes

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

i have two scenes in a reality composer file(.rcproject). Each scene has a model entity attached to an image, when the image is detected by the camera, the model appears

My implementation is like the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76139028/adding-gestures-to-all-model-entities-in-one-reality-composer-scene-not-just-on), but i only can interact with one model
Thank you for reading my question.